# How Clean GDI objects and User Objects

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, gdi, user-object

I Have an `windows form app` which generate dynamically 
`tabpages`,`controls`,`datagridviews` and all the `events` are dynimically
using so when `control` generate `GDI objects` and `User objects` does not 
clean everytime current `objects` plus in previous `objects` that y 1 time come my app will crash . I can 
`dispose` all `controls`,`clear` all `controls`,`force` to `garbage`
collector,NULL THE `OBJECT` `ARRAY` memory etc etc  everything I can do
but in my senario does'nt clean `GDI Objects` and  `UserObjects` when work
Finish I'm sharing code with u guyx plx some help me

Here is My Public Array Objects

```
 public TabPage[] tab = new TabPage[20];
    public DataGridView[] rtb = new DataGridView[20];
    public TextBox[] txt = new TextBox[20];
    public TextBox[] txt1 = new TextBox[20];

    public TextBox[] aoid = new TextBox[20];
    public TextBox[] soid = new TextBox[20];

    public Button[] getar = new Button[20];
    public Button[] getsi = new Button[20];

    private TextBox[] txt2 = new TextBox[20];
    private TextBox[] txt3 = new TextBox[20];
    private Label[] lbl = new Label[20];
    private Label[] lbl1 = new Label[20];
    private Label[] lbl2 = new Label[20];
    private Label[] lbl3 = new Label[20];
    private Label[] pwl = new Label[20];
    private TextBox[] pwt = new TextBox[20];
    private TextBox[] txt4 = new TextBox[20];
    private Label[] pc_carton = new Label[20];
    private TextBox[] pcs_carton = new TextBox[20];
    private Label[] un = new Label[20];
    private TextBox[] units = new TextBox[20];
    private Label[] refno_l = new Label[20];
    private TextBox[] refno_t = new TextBox[20];

    private Label[] pro_l = new Label[20];
    private TextBox[] pro_t = new TextBox[20];

    private Label[] inlay_l = new Label[20];
    public TextBox[] inlay_t = new TextBox[20];
    public TextBox[] inlay_i = new TextBox[20];
    private Button[] getin = new Button[20];

    private Label[] yarn_l = new Label[20];
    public TextBox[] yarn_t = new TextBox[20];
    public TextBox[] yarn_i = new TextBox[20];
    private Button[] getyrn = new Button[20];
    private Label[] order_l = new Label[20];
    public TextBox[] order_t = new TextBox[20];
    //private Label[] inlayl = new Label[8];
    //private TextBox[] inlayt = new TextBox[8];


    public TextBox[] txt5 = new TextBox[6];
    public TextBox[] txt6 = new TextBox[6];

    private Label[] kd_l = new Label[20];
    public TextBox[] kd_t = new TextBox[20];

    private Label[] date_l = new Label[20];
    private DateTimePicker[] date_p = new DateTimePicker[20];

    private CheckBox[] checkb = new CheckBox[20];
    private TextBox[] checkt = new TextBox[20];
    private Label[] spec_l = new Label[20];
    public RichTextBox[] spec_t = new RichTextBox[20];

    private Label[] ean_l = new Label[20];
    public RichTextBox[] ean_t = new RichTextBox[20];
```

Here Is Control Generate based on TextBox Value

```
try
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                k = 0;
                //s = 0;
                tabControl2.TabPages.Clear();
                k = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);
                k1 = k - tabControl2.TabPages.Count;
                //cc = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);
                if (k > 20)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You Exceed Limit");
                }
                else
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
                    {
                        tab[i] = new TabPage();

                        //tab[i] = new TabPage();
                        rtb[i] = new DataGridView();
                        //Start Gridview
                        rtb[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
                        rtb[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 110);
                        rtb[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top;
                        rtb[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1020, 230);
                        rtb[i].AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;

                        foreach (DataGridViewColumn dcol in rtb[i].Columns)
                        {
                            dcol.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                        }



                        //ID Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("tr_id", "ID");
                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].ReadOnly = true;
                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].Width = 1;
                        rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].Visible = false;
                        //rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].ReadOnly = true;

                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("Counter", "SNo");
                        rtb[i].Columns["Counter"].ReadOnly = true;

                        //rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].ReadOnly = true;
                        //rtb[i].Columns["tr_id"].Width = 10;
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("color_id", "id");

                        rtb[i].Columns["color_id"].Visible = false;
                        // Color Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("color_name", "Color Name");
                        rtb[i].Columns["color_name"].ReadOnly = true;
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("color_no", "Pantone No.");
                        rtb[i].Columns["color_no"].ReadOnly = true;
                        //Quantity Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("quantity", "Quantity");

                        //Piece Weight Column
                        //rtb[i].Columns.Add("piece_weight", "Piece Weight");
                        //Total Weight Carton
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("total_weight", "Total Weight");
                        rtb[i].Columns["total_weight"].ReadOnly = true;
                        //Piece in Carton Column
                        //rtb[i].Columns.Add("pcs_carton", "Pcs/Carton");
                        //No Of Carton Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("no_of_carton", "Total Cartons");
                        //rtb[i].Columns["no_of_carton"].ReadOnly = true;
                        //Unit Name Column
                        //rtb[i].Columns.Add("unit_name", "Unit Name");
                        //Rate Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("rate", "Rate");
                        //Amount Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("amount", "Amount");
                        rtb[i].Columns["amount"].ReadOnly = true;
                        //Ship Qty Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("ship_qty", "Ship Qty.");
                        //kdnr column
                        // rtb[i].Columns.Add("kdnr", "KDNR");
                        //reference No Column
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add("ref_no", "Reference No./Ean No");

                        //Article No/Product No
                        //rtb[i].Columns.Add("artno", "Art. No./Prd. No.");

                        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                        checkColumn.Name = "deleterow";
                        checkColumn.HeaderText = "Delete Row";
                        checkColumn.Width = 50;
                        checkColumn.ReadOnly = false;
                        checkColumn.FillWeight = 10; //if the datagridview is resized (on form resize) the checkbox won't take up too much; value is relative to the other columns' fill values
                        checkColumn.Visible = false;
                        rtb[i].Columns.Add(checkColumn);

                        //DataGridViewButtonColumn btcol2 = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

                        //btcol2.HeaderText = "Delete";
                        //btcol2.Name = "delete";
                        //btcol2.Text = "Delete";
                        //btcol2.Width = 50;
                        //btcol2.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

                        //rtb[i].Columns.Add(btcol2);


                        //End Gridview

                        rtb[i].AllowUserToAddRows = false;

                        //Start txt0
                        txt[i] = new TextBox();
                        txt[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 0);
                        txt[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 20);
                        txt[i].Enabled = false;
                        //End txt0

                        getar[i] = new Button();
                        getar[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(241, 0);
                        getar[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 20);
                        getar[i].Text = "Get";

                        aoid[i] = new TextBox();
                        aoid[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 0);
                        aoid[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 20);
                        aoid[i].Visible = false;
                        //Start Label0
                        lbl[i] = new Label();
                        lbl[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                        lbl[i].Text = "Article Name:";
                        lbl[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
                        //End Label0

                        //Start Label1
                        lbl1[i] = new Label();
                        lbl1[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(280, 0);
                        lbl1[i].Text = "Size:";
                        lbl1[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 20);
                        //End
                        soid[i] = new TextBox();
                        soid[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(320, 0);
                        soid[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 20);
                        soid[i].Visible = false;
                        //start txt1
                        txt1[i] = new TextBox();
                        txt1[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(320, 0);
                        txt1[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 20);
                        txt1[i].ReadOnly = true;
                        //txt1[i].Text = "asdf";
                        //end txt1
                        getsi[i] = new Button();
                        getsi[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(489, 0);
                        getsi[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 20);
                        getsi[i].Text = "Get";
                        ////Start Label2
                        //lbl2[i] = new Label();
                        //lbl2[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(320, 0);
                        //lbl2[i].Text = "Special Instruction:";
                        //lbl2[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
                        ////End Label2

                        ////start txt2
                        //txt2[i] = new TextBox();
                        //txt2[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(420, 0);
                        //txt2[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250, 50);
                        //txt2[i].Multiline = true;
                        ////end txt2

                        ////start lbl3
                        lbl3[i] = new Label();
                        lbl3[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(530, 0);
                        lbl3[i].Text = "Packs :";
                        lbl3[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
                        ////end lbl3

                        ////start txt3
                        txt3[i] = new TextBox();
                        txt3[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(580, 0);
                        txt3[i].Text = "1";
                        ////end txt3

                        ////start lbl3
                        pwl[i] = new Label();
                        pwl[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(690, 0);
                        pwl[i].Text = "Piece Weight";
                        pwl[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
                        ////end lbl3

                        ////start txt3
                        pwt[i] = new TextBox();
                        pwt[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(770, 0);
                        pwt[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
                        //pwt[i].Text = "1";
                        ////end txt3

                        ////start lbl3
                        pc_carton[i] = new Label();
                        pc_carton[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(820, 0);
                        pc_carton[i].Text = "Pcs Carton";
                        pc_carton[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 20);
                        ////end lbl3

                        ////start txt3
                        pcs_carton[i] = new TextBox();
                        pcs_carton[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(890, 0);
                        pcs_carton[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
                        //pwt[i].Text = "1";
                        ////end txt3

                        ////start lbl3
                        un[i] = new Label();
                        un[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(940, 0);
                        un[i].Text = "Unit Name";
                        un[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 20);
                        ////end lbl3


                        ////start lbl3
                        pro_l[i] = new Label();
                        pro_l[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 30);
                        pro_l[i].Text = "Program No.:";
                        pro_l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);

                        ////end lbl3

                        ////start txt3
                        pro_t[i] = new TextBox();
                        pro_t[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 30);
                        pro_t[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 20);
                        pro_t[i].MaxLength = 1;
                        //pro_t[i].Text = "1";
                        ////end txt3

                        //Start txt0
                        inlay_t[i] = new TextBox();
                        inlay_t[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(137, 30);
                        inlay_t[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 20);
                        inlay_t[i].Enabled = false;
                        //End txt0

                        getin[i] = new Button();
                        getin[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(306, 30);
                        getin[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 20);
                        getin[i].Text = "Get";

                        inlay_i[i] = new TextBox();
                        inlay_i[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(137, 30);
                        inlay_i[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 20);
                        inlay_i[i].Visible = false;
                        //Start Label0
                        inlay_l[i] = new Label();
                        inlay_l[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(105, 30);
                        inlay_l[i].Text = "Inlay:";
                        inlay_l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 20);
                        //End Label0

                        //Start Label1
                        yarn_l[i] = new Label();
                        yarn_l[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(346, 30);
                        yarn_l[i].Text = "Yarn:";
                        yarn_l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(32, 20);
                        //End
                        yarn_i[i] = new TextBox();
                        yarn_i[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(378, 30);
                        yarn_i[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(10, 20);
                        yarn_i[i].Visible = false;
                        //start txt1
                        yarn_t[i] = new TextBox();
                        yarn_t[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(378, 30);
                        yarn_t[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(169, 20);
                        yarn_t[i].ReadOnly = true;
                        //txt1[i].Text = "asdf";


                        //end txt1
                        getyrn[i] = new Button();
                        getyrn[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(547, 30);
                        getyrn[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 20);
                        getyrn[i].Text = "Get";

                        order_l[i] = new Label();
                        order_l[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(580, 30);
                        order_l[i].Text = "Order No.";
                        order_l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);



                        order_t[i] = new TextBox();
                        order_t[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(650, 30);
                        order_t[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(129, 20);
                        // order_t[i].ReadOnly = true;
                        //////start txt3
                        //refno_t[i] = new TextBox();
                        kd_l[i] = new Label();
                        kd_l[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(785, 30);
                        kd_l[i].Text = "KDNR";
                        kd_l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 20);



                        kd_t[i] = new TextBox();
                        kd_t[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(825, 30);
                        kd_t[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(129, 20);

                        //refno_t[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(990, 0);
                        //refno_t[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 40);

                        date_l[i] = new Label();
                        date_l[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(955, 30);
                        date_l[i].Text = "Ship. Date";
                        date_l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 20);

                        //refno_t[i].Multiline = true;
                        ////pwt[i].Text = "1";
                        date_p[i] = new DateTimePicker();
                        // date_p[i].Name = "DyanmicDateTimePicker";

                        date_p[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1020, 30);
                        date_p[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 25);
                        date_p[i].Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                        date_p[i].Text = dateTimePicker_shipmentdate.Text;
                        ////end txt3
                        checkb[i] = new CheckBox();
                        checkb[i].Location = new Point(1115, 30);
                        checkb[i].Text = "";
                        checkb[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);

                        ////start txt4
                        checkt[i] = new TextBox();
                        checkt[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1140, 30);
                        checkt[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 25);
                        checkt[i].ReadOnly = true;
                        checkt[i].Text = "1";
                        //txt3[i].Text = "1";
                        ////end txt4

                        spec_l[i] = new Label();
                        spec_l[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 60);
                        spec_l[i].Text = "Special Instruction:";
                        spec_l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);

                        spec_t[i] = new RichTextBox();
                        spec_t[i].Location = new Point(101, 60);
                        spec_t[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);


                        ean_l[i] = new Label();
                        ean_l[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(365, 60);
                        ean_l[i].Text = "Ean Codes:";
                        ean_l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);

                        ean_t[i] = new RichTextBox();
                        ean_t[i].Location = new Point(445, 60);
                        ean_t[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 50);


                        ////start txt4
                        txt4[i] = new TextBox();
                        txt4[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1050, 30);
                        txt4[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1, 1);
                        //txt3[i].Text = "1";
                        ////end txt4

                        tab[i].Controls.Add(lbl[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(txt[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(lbl1[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(txt1[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(lbl2[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(txt2[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(lbl3[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(txt3[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(pwl[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(pwt[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(pc_carton[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(pcs_carton[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(un[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(units[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(txt4[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(getar[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(getsi[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(aoid[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(soid[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(pro_l[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(pro_t[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(inlay_l[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(inlay_t[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(inlay_i[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(getin[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(yarn_l[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(yarn_t[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(yarn_i[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(getyrn[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(order_l[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(order_t[i]);

                        tab[i].Controls.Add(kd_l[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(kd_t[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(date_l[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(date_p[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(checkb[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(checkt[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(spec_l[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(spec_t[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(ean_l[i]);
                        tab[i].Controls.Add(ean_t[i]);
                        //tab[i].Controls.Add(refno_l[i]);
                        //tab[i].Controls.Add(refno_t[i]);
                        //tab[i].Controls.Add(lbl5[i]);
                        //tab[i].Text = txt1[i].Text;

                        tab[i].Controls.Add(rtb[i]);
                        tab[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
                        tab[i].Name = "tab" + i.ToString();
                        tab[i].Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
                        tab[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 242);
                        tab[i].Text = "Article" + i.ToString();
                        tab[i].UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                        tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tab[i]);

                        #region Auto Complete For Unit Name

                        try
                        {

                            //TextBox te = e.Control as TextBox;
                            units[i].AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                            units[i].AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] { "Piece", "Packs", "Mtr", "Kg." });
                            units[i].AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                            //txt[i].AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                            //txt[i].AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                            //txt[i].AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection1;

                        }
                        catch (Exception aa) { MessageBox.Show(aa.Message); }

                        #endregion
                        rtb[i].RowContextMenuStripNeeded += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowContextMenuStripNeededEventHandler(this.dataGridView_RowContextMenuStripNeeded);
                        this.deleteRowToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.deleteRowToolStripMenuItem_Click1);
                        //MessageBox.Show(""+tab[i].Text);
                        rtb[i].KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(rtb_KeyDown);
                        rtb[i].RowEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView_RowEnter);
                        rtb[i].KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(rtb_KeyDown);
                        rtb[i].EditingControlShowing += new DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventHandler(dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing);
                        txt1[i].Leave += new System.EventHandler(txt1_Leave);
                        rtb[i].CellEndEdit += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView_CellEndEdit);
                        getar[i].Click += new EventHandler(getarticle_Click);
                        getsi[i].Click += new EventHandler(getsize_Click);
                        this.pro_t[i].KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textch_KeyPress);
                        getyrn[i].Click += new EventHandler(getyarn_Click);
                        getin[i].Click += new EventHandler(getinlay_Click);
                        checkb[i].CheckedChanged += new System.EventHandler(CheckBoxChanged);
                        //this.rtb[i].DefaultValuesNeeded += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowEventHandler(this.dataGridView_DefaultValuesNeeded);
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using array types for your controls? For example, you have declared "pro_l" as "Label[] pro_l = new Label[20]", but you are using it as a non-array type in your code above: "pro_l = new Label()". What are you trying to do?

Comment: GDI resources will be cleaned up if you use `Dispose` - and after 1 year (really?) the Garbage collector **will** have removed every non-used resources - so you keep hold of them somewhere - but to be honest: in this mess it's impossible to find. I would advise using a memory-profiler to find the offending lines/objects.

Comment: i update my question #sujaysharma

Answer (score 0):

When you bind an event with any control, it does not get disposed unless parent does so before  removing do -= also.
also if you can create Blocks , use keyword using to create scope of every created object.

Comment: i'm removing events also like -= but nothing change